# Multiple Id's calling on same JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying out a JavaScript where it takes Id of an image and onclick of the image it performs some function. But I have multiple Id's of same image where the id of the onclick'ed image should be processed by JavaScript and the operation should be performed.
Problem is I am not able to get the right id based on the click.

here is my code

1)myhtml

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<div class="sub-process-block quantity">
    <h3>choose quantity</h3>
    <div id="example" onclick="changeImage()">
       <img src="img/carton-empty.png" id="myImage">
       <img src="img/carton-empty.png" id="myImage1">
       <img src="img/carton-empty.png" id="myImage2">
    </div>
</div>
```

2)javascript

```
<script>
  function changeImage() {
   var imageArray=["myImage","myImage1","myImage2"];
      for(var i=0;i<imageArray.length;i++ ){
        image = document.getElementById(imageArray[i]).onclick;
      }
      if(image.src.match("selected")) {
        image.src="img/carton-empty.png";
      }else{
        image.src = "img/carton selected.png";
      }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using Jquery?

Comment: Why are you using same id for multiple objects?

Comment: Can u show us some code?

Comment: We won't be able to help without you showing us some code.

Comment: sorry forgot to put my code

Comment: i am not using jquery and the id's are different

Comment: what is `image = document.getElementById(imageArray[i]).onclick;` supposed to be? do you realize (I guess no) that this is equivalent to `image = null` in your case?

Comment: i am trying to get the id of the image that was clicked, I know that is not the right way to get it, so need some help on it

Comment: jquery code will also be fine if someone can help on it.

Comment: `event.target.id` - id of the clicked image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add an event listener to your images in JS? Then you can check if it's selected or not and update the source accordingly

```
// get all images and put them in an array
var images = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'));

// loop through images and add event listener
images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.addEventListener('click', onImageClick);
});

// on click, check if image is selected and update src
function onImageClick(e) {
    var image = e.target;

  if (image.src.match("selected")) {
    // is selected, now unselected it and update src
    image.setAttribute('src', 'img/carton-empty.png');
  } else {
    // is not selected, now select it and update src
    image.setAttribute('src', 'img/carton selected.png');
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qzdsf8r/4/

Inspect the image elements in the dev tools and see the class and src change.

Comment: var images = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img')); 
for this line should i add the id's of the images like
var images = ["myImage","myImage1","myImage2"].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'));

Comment: No, you can't. If you really need to get the images by ID, you should edit the script a little, see https://jsfiddle.net/0qzdsf8r/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
function changeImage(){
  var imageArray = ["myImage", "myImage1", "myImage2"];
  for(var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++){
    var image = document.getElementById(imageArray[i]);

    if(image.src.match("selected")){
      image.src = "img/carton-empty.png";
    }else{
      image.src = "img/carton selected.png";
    }
  }
}
```

You placed condition outside for loop;

Comment: it selects all the images but not exactly the image i clicked